# realm react-native - 2 different databases/schemas

Tags: react-native, realm

can someone show me how to create 2 databases with realm?

I have 2 screens. Screen "Coins" contains working code below. I want to add another realm database to the screen "Cars".

Unfortunately an error occurs:

**"Realm at path '/Users/......./Documents/default.realm' already opened on current thread with different schema**

```
//Screen "Coins"

var Realm = require('realm');

realm_coins = new Realm({
  schema: [{
    name: "Coins",
    properties: {
      coins: "int"
    }
  }]
})
```

If i add the following to the Screen "Cars", the mentioned error occurrs

```
//Screen "Cars"

var Realm = require('realm');

realm_cars = new Realm({
  schema: [{
    name: "Cars",
    properties: {
      name: "string"
    }
  }]
})
```

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the titles around here.  If you have an answer, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your `Realm` instance, you pass in an array of your schema definitions:

```
const realm = new Realm({
  schema: [{
    name: "Coins",
    properties: {
      coins: "int"
    }
  }, {
    name: "Cars",
    properties: {
      name: "string"
    }
  }]
});
```